# How to get something iterable out of a JSON String?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse an Object which is in JSON format like
`[{"id": "1", "revisionId":"2"}, {"id":"3", "revisionId":"4"}]`

I want to extract the ids to be an iterable array like
`["1", "3"]`

I have tried using the JSONObject library but it seems when I do this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(obj);
```

it converts the object into a structure like
`{"empty":false}`
so using `jsonObject.get("id")` doesn't work.

Comment: What library are you using to parse JSON?  What is `obj` in the provided Java code?

Comment: It is an array so you can convert it to collection by gson or jackson

Answer (score 1):

Your json string is a json array, not an object, so you can't pass that to `JSONObject`, but you can use a [JSONArray](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html) instead.
To get the list of object IDs, you can try something like:

```
List<String> ids = new JsonArray(obj).toList()  // turn the JSONArray into a list
        .stream()
        .map(JSONObject.class::cast)            // cast elements to JSONObjects
        .map(json -> json.getString("id"))      // extract the id from each object
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you try to parse a json array:
'[{"id": "1", "revisionId":"2"}, {"id":"3", "revisionId":"4"}]'

into a JSONObject. Try something like that:
'{"array": [{"id": "1", "revisionId":"2"}, {"id":"3", "revisionId":"4"}]}'

Then you can access the array with new 
'JSONObject(jsonString).getJSONArray("array");'

Let me know if it work for you :-)